# Insert a space between 2 echo

Tags: php, echo, space

How do I add a space in the returned text between `sample1` and `sample2`? Here is what I have so far:

```
if ($eventid!="") { 
   echo $get_event['sample1'], $get_event['sample2']; 
}
```

Comment: if($eventid!=""){echo $get_event['sample1] , $get_event['sample2']; }

Comment: Are you missing a single quote after `'sample1`?

Answer (score 4):

It's really simple, just `echo` a space between the variables...

```
<?php if($eventid!=""){echo $get_event['sample1'] , ' ', $get_event['sample2']; }
```

Comment: @MelanyChang Simply change the string to `' , '`.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation always make things cleaner and easier:

```
if (!empty($eventid)) {
    echo $get_event['sample1'] . ' ' . $get_event['sample2'];
}
```

On PHP, you need to use a dot (.) to concatenate strings... as you can see on the **Strings Operators** documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: `echo` accepts multiple params as well, like the OP has used.

Comment: @alex I didn't say it doesn't, both ways works.. Since he asked about concatenation, I said something about the dot and not multiple echo params, since you can't always "concatenate" strings with commas